# emptyItemClass for Kendo UI Sortable for Angular

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-sortable

I am probably missing something basic but I cannot seem to get [emptyItemClass](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/sortable/api/SortableComponent/#toc-emptyitemclass) to be applied to a kendo-UI sortable component for angular 2.

I have also tried using emptyItemStyle, and get the same result.

```
<kendo-sortable [data]="viewColumns" itemClass="itemClass" emptyItemClass="emptyItem" activeItemClass="activeItemClass"
[emptyText]="'No columns selected'" (dragEnd)="doneDragging($event)">
```

In this above code snipit itemClass and activeItemClass work, but emptyItemClass does not.

[Here is a StackBlitz of my problem](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uzqwxt?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the brackets in your example and also use `ViewEncapsulation`.

[Working StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uzqwxt-exm3pt)

Comment: Thanks.  This does work.  There just seems to be something wrong with having to set viewEncapsulation to none to get the styles to be applied...